# Given a commutative local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$, then why is it true that $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2 = \mathfrak m \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m.$

Tags: ring-theory

Given a commutative local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$, then why is it true that

$$\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2 = \mathfrak m \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m.$$

Essentially I have reduced the problem to showing that $x\otimes 1_{R/\mathfrak{m}} = 0$ implies $x \in \mathfrak{m^2}$

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you prove that $M/IM = M \otimes_R R/I$ for any ring $R$, module $M$ and ideal $I$?

Comment: If I could then I'd be done. I have a sneaky suspicion that it would require showing that $x\otimes 1_{R/I} = 0$ implies $x \in IM$. And I'd be back to where I was left off?

Answer (score 2):

For any ring $R$ and any ideal $I$, there is an exact sequence of $R$-modules

$$
0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0.
$$

Apply the functor $I\otimes_R-$, which is right-exact, to get the exact sequence

$$
I\otimes_R I\to I\to I\otimes_R R/I\to 0.
$$

The image of the map $I\otimes_R I\to I$ is $I^2$, whence the result from the first-isomorphism theorem for modules.

Comment: I guess the difficulty here is showing that $I\otimes_{R} -$ is right-exact? Do you have a reference to the proof of this?

Comment: The functor $M\otimes_R-$ is right-exact for any right-module. A "down to earth" element-theoretic proof is in Jacobson, "Basic Algebra 2", p.132 and presumably any other book that introduces the tensor product. Alternatively, you can read pp.51-53 in Weibel's "Introduction to Homological Algebra", to find out that $M\otimes_R-$ is also a left-adjoint (Hom-Tensor adjoint), and any left-adjoint additive functor of abelian categories is right-exact.